# Disaggregate quarterly data to daily data in R keeping values?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

How does one easily disaggregate quarterly data to daily data? In this case I'm using 10 years of US GDP data which have quarterly observations, and I want to expand the data frame to daily level, carrying over the GDP value each day until the next observation.

Reprex table:

```
structure(list(thedate = structure(c(14426, 14518, 14610, 14700, 
14791, 14883, 14975, 15065, 15156, 15248, 15340, 15431, 15522, 
15614, 15706, 15796, 15887, 15979, 16071, 16161, 16252, 16344, 
16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 17075, 17167, 
17257, 17348, 17440, 17532, 17622, 17713, 17805, 17897, 17987
), class = "Date"), gdp = c(1.5, 4.5, 1.5, 3.7, 3, 2, -1, 2.9, 
-0.1, 4.7, 3.2, 1.7, 0.5, 0.5, 3.6, 0.5, 3.2, 3.2, -1.1, 5.5, 
5, 2.3, 3.2, 3, 1.3, 0.1, 2, 1.9, 2.2, 2, 2.3, 2.2, 3.2, 3.5, 
2.5, 3.5, 2.9, 1.1, 3.1, 2.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

We see above:

```
2009-07-01 | 1.5
2009-10-01 | 4.5
```

The intended output would look like:

```
2009-07-01 | 1.5
2009-07-02 | 1.5
2009-07-03 | 1.5
etc.
2009-10-01 | 4.5
2009-10-02 | 4.5
2009-10-03 | 4.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tidyr and zoo package answer that uses 'last observation carried forward' after inserting a sequence of dates with NA:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

data %>%
  complete(thedate = seq.Date(min(thedate), max(thedate), by="day")) %>%
  do(na.locf(.))
```

**Edit**: Thanks to Shree for reminding that tidyr::fill would eliminate need for zoo:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  complete(thedate = seq.Date(min(thedate), max(thedate), by="day")) %>%
  fill(gdp)
```

Comment: `tidyr::fill(gdp)` will also do it in case you want stick to `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution:

```
last_quarter_end_date <- seq.Date(df$thedate[nrow(df)], by = 'quarter', length.out = 2)[-1]-1
seqs <- diff(c(df$thedate, last_quarter_end_date))

data.frame(thedate = rep(df$thedate, seqs) + sequence(seqs)-1
           , gdp = rep(df$gdp, seqs))
```

Basically, the difference between dates is how many times you need to repeat a GDP column. Also, I can do `seq_len()` for each difference to add back to the original date.

**Performance**
This approach is efficient although I'll note that 0.6 ms isn't really much different than 15 ms in the big picture.

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq     max neval
 cole_base   528.1   554.15   690.379   644.9   663.75  3225.7   100
  d_b_base 15735.0 15994.40 17395.754 16243.9 18108.30 38761.8   100
 Ben_tidyr  2808.7  2936.40  3356.324  3076.6  3149.65  8065.1   100
```

Complete code for reference:

```
DF <- structure(list(thedate = structure(c(14426, 14518, 14610, 14700, 
                                           14791, 14883, 14975, 15065, 15156, 15248, 15340, 15431, 15522, 
                                           15614, 15706, 15796, 15887, 15979, 16071, 16161, 16252, 16344, 
                                           16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 17075, 17167, 
                                           17257, 17348, 17440, 17532, 17622, 17713, 17805, 17897, 17987
), class = "Date"), gdp = c(1.5, 4.5, 1.5, 3.7, 3, 2, -1, 2.9, 
                            -0.1, 4.7, 3.2, 1.7, 0.5, 0.5, 3.6, 0.5, 3.2, 3.2, -1.1, 5.5, 
                            5, 2.3, 3.2, 3, 1.3, 0.1, 2, 1.9, 2.2, 2, 2.3, 2.2, 3.2, 3.5, 
                            2.5, 3.5, 2.9, 1.1, 3.1, 2.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                -40L))

library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyr)

microbenchmark(cole_base = {
  last_quarter_end_date <- seq.Date(DF$thedate[nrow(DF)], by = 'quarter', length.out = 2)[-1]-1
  seqs <- diff(c(DF$thedate, last_quarter_end_date))

  data.frame(thedate = rep(DF$thedate, seqs) + sequence(seqs)-1
             , gdp = rep(DF$gdp, seqs))
}
, d_b_base = {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(2:NROW(DF), function(i){
    data.frame(date = head(seq.Date(DF$thedate[i-1], DF$thedate[i], "days"), -1),
               gdp = DF$gdp[i - 1])
     }))
}
, Ben_tidyr = {
  DF %>%
    complete(thedate = seq.Date(min(thedate), max(thedate), by="day")) %>%
    fill(gdp)
}
)
```